# Using Fyne to bind a list widget to a slice of structs

Tags: go, fyne

I have a collection of data items and am trying to use Fyne to put together a GUI to edit the collection. I've figured out how to use binding to display the collection, but I can't figure out how to then be able to edit the items.

Here's a slightly simplified version of what I have:

```
type Item struct {
  Name string
  Slot1 bool
  Slot2 bool
}

type ItemList struct {
  Items []Item
}
```

I won't show them, but I've added the methods to these two types so that the former implements `binding.DataItem` and the latter implements `binding.DataList`.

Now for the display:

```
var dataList := ItemList{
 ...
 ...
}

list := NewListWithData(
        dataList,
        func() fyne.CanvasObject {
           label := widget.NewLabel("placeholder")
           c1 := widget.NewCheck("", func(bool) {})
           c2 := widget.NewCheck("", func(bool) {})
           return container.NewHBox(label, c1, c2)
        },
        func(di binding.DatItem, obj fyne.CanvasObject) {
           ct := obj.(*fyne.Container)
           label := ct.Objects[0].(*widget.Label)
           c1 := ct.Objects[1].(*widget.Check)
           c2 := ct.Objects[2].(*widget.Check)
           item := di.(Item)
           label.SetText(item.Name)
           c1.SetChecked(item.Slot1)
           c2.SetChecked(item.Slot2)
        },
}
```

I suspect that at this point I need to do something like `values := binding.BindStruct(&item)`, but if I do so, I'm not sure how to then get those into the label and check widgets.

Comment: would love to see how you implemented those interfaces, it's so hard to get it from the source with no examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wire up the input controls to the binding (the item for the struct is passed in through `di`). If you already have the methods in `Item` that gain you access to the child items bound then you're most of the way there.

To wire up the edit capabilities replace `label.SetText(...)` with `label.Bind(...)` and `c1.SetChecked(...)` with `c1.Bind(...)`. This will both set the current values an

Comment: Thanks @andy.xyz, This is slowly getting more clear. I tried `c1.Bind(binding.BindBool(&mi.Slot1))` -- seems to be what you're suggesting. It compiles, but it doesn't  change the underlying data structure. I've read the book "Building Cross-Platform GUI Applications with Fyne" and I think I understand the examples there, but they don't quite help me understand this more complicated situation. I've done a little Googling but couldn't turn up a better example. Are you aware of one you could point me to?

Comment: Almost - but you should use your DataItem (`di`) as your source (I can’t see what `mi` is so maybe that is what you meant). Perhaps if your `Item` implemented `DataMap` like the result of `BindStruct` would do then you can `label.Bind(di.(Item).Slot1Item()` (returning a data item instead of creating new bindings on the fly).

Comment: When you bind values as you are doing it is critical that you are using a pointer to the original data source. Any intermediate variables will break the two-way-bind flow.